# Pining to jumplist

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio, jumplist

I am trying to pin a solution to a Visual Studio jump list. But the instructions don't seem to work. The instructions say:

- open the jump list
- point to the item and click the pin

But when I point to the item (on the desktop) the start menu closes.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I do not understand the problem, can you give more details ? What instruction ?

Answer (score 2):

Pinning items should be performed when they are open, or when you can mouse over them under the jump list itself. Recently and frequently opened items appear on jump lists and pinning them is just a matter of following the appropriate steps.

To pin to the task bar you need to have the file open then right click > 'pin this item...'.

To pin to the start menu you follow the same concept, mouse over the item and right click > 'pin this item...'.

Attached is a screenshot detailing how to pin to a jump list in the Start Menu.

[image: Pinning items to jump lists in the Start Menu]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to pin a solution that is on your desktop to the Visual Studio Jump List.  As you have found, that does not work because the Jump List loses focus and disappears when you click anything that is outside of it.

What you need to do is open the solution once, so it appears in the Jump List under the "Recent" heading.  Once it is there, mousing over it will show a "pin" icon (See screenshot below).  Click the pin icon to pin the solution.

[image]